# setState not working in react hooks when using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, setstate

What I'm trying to do is : after manipulating the data of each user in the "users" array I want to add it to a state called newUser, then push that new user to an array called newUsersList. How can I do that?
(the users array here is simplified)

```js
export default function App() {
  const users = [
    {
      nom: 'name 1',
      prenom: 'last name 1',
    },
    {
      nom: 'name 2',
      prenom: 'last name 2',
    },
    {
      nom: 'name 3',
      prenom: 'last name 3',
    },
    {
      nom: 'name 4',
      prenom: 'last name 4',
    },
    {
      nom: 'name 5',
      prenom: 'last name 5',
    },
    {
      nom: 'name 6',
      prenom: 'last name 6',
    },
  ];
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({});
  const [newUsersList, setNewUsersList] = useState([]);
  const handleClick = () => {
    users.map((user) => {
      setNewUser(
        {
          firstName: user.nom,
          lastName: user.prenom,
        },
        newUsersList.push(newUser),
      );
      //newUsersList.push(newUser)
    });
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   newUsersList.push(...users, newUser)
  // }, [newUser])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}> Add Users </button>
      {newUsersList.map((user) => {
        return <h6> user name : {user.firstName} </h6>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem here is that the setNewUser function is not working and as you can see I tried 3 solutions :

1. running newUsersList.push(newUser) after executing setNewUser
2. added newUsersList.push(newUser) as a second parameter to setNewUser
3. called newUsersList.push(newUser) inside useEffect when the newUser state changes

None of these solutions is working.

Runnable code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-joana-82qcc?file=/src/App.js:69-1375

Note that this is an extracted code and the original one has a more complicated json data that I'm manipulating. And I got stuck when changing the state of the newUser.

Comment: `setNextUser` won't magically change your local variable `nextUser`, it will asynchronously change the _state_. Probably this is the misconception you are stuck on?

Comment: You are changing `newUsersList` directly. You should never do this and instead use the setter.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add each user's data to a state called newUser, then push that user to an array called newUsersList. How can I do that?

Comment: @sagi I think this is it, so how to do that?

Comment: which user do you want to set inside `newUser` ? i can suggest an answer if i know the purpose of `newUser`

Comment: I want each user inside the users Array to be set in the newUser state after manipulating  its data then push the newUser to the newUsersList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `handleClick` to:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  updatedUsers = users.map((user) => ({ firstName: user.nom, lastName: user.prenom }))
  setNewUsersList([...newUsersList,...updatedUsers]);
};
```

Two notes: First, never change a state directly, but always use its setter. Second, it doesn't seems like you need `newUser` state at all

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I'm trying to do, note that this is an extracted code and the original one has a more complicated json data that I'm manipulating. And I got stuck when changing the state of the newUser.

Comment: Then you should define your problem better. Explain the logic behind this, and what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: I added my last comment at the end of the question. Thanks!

Comment: How do you define a `newUser` ? Where does it come from?

Comment: const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({});

Comment: If you already handle the logic behind `newUser` correctly, then see edit.

Comment: I tried it but the state of the newUser is as always empty. You can test your solution in the runnable code that I added: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-joana-82qcc?file=/src/App.js:69-1144

Comment: That's why I asked how you define a newUser? Where does it's data comes from? You should update `newUser` in a different place, and call `handleClick` when it already contains the user info..

Comment: the newUser state is supposed to change inside map. That's exactly what I'm trying to solve. The setNewUser is not changing the new user's state.

Comment: If you test your solution, now the newUser state is set as the last user (user 6) when I click on the button

Comment: See my edit, still not sure I understood you..

Comment: That's it, thank you so much! here is the new runnable code if anyone wants to test it: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-rui-zyl15?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Np man, cheers :)